# Coordinates in {4,3,6} hyperbolic honeycomb

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I'd like to make a maze or a game that is played in the [Order-6 cubic honeycomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-6_cubic_honeycomb). I like the fact that there are infinitely many cells at each vertex. However, I need some kind of coordinates here.

The coordinate system must be capable of these actions:

- If I venture into the same cell by two different ways, I should be able to recognise that both endpoints are the same.
- My orientation should not change by travelling into another cell (i.e. there is no preferred orientation). For example: I go one cell up, one cell forwards, one cell down, one cell backwards, one cell up, one cell forwards. Now I should end in the same cell as I began but also upside down.
- Travelling like 20 cells in one direction shouldn't have any distorsive effects.

My only idea is storing a way from origin to the given cell but:

- How do I get if two ways lead to the same point?
- What if the path is unneccessarily long?

EDIT: Here is an image showing what I mean by the "orientation should not change". The arrow shows my orientation which does not change (from my perspective, there are only right angles). The picture shows intended behaviour.
[image]

Comment: "My orientation should not change by travelling into another cell" ... "Now I should end in the same cell as I began but also upside down." ??? If your orientation does not change, why would you be upside down? Hyperbolic space is still orientable.

Comment: I draw an arrow pointing up into one cell. Then I perform these 6 steps. After that, I should see the arrow pointing down.

Comment: I added a picture which explains what I mean.

Comment: That is not keeping the same orientation as you move from one cell to the next. I don't have an answer for your coordinate question, but suggest that you look at the dual tesselation [Order-4 hexagonal tiling honeycomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-4_hexagonal_tiling_honeycomb). There the cells become nodes and moving from cell to cell corresponds to travel along edges. This converts your hypergeometric tesselation problem into a graph, which likely will be easier to figure out.